# Memcached Tennis Match with Replication

Tags: memcached

Tennis Match with Replication
Use Memcached to store the points of Roger Federer (referred as F) and Rafael Nadal (referred as N). The initial scores are 0-0.

Note: Telnet to install instance 1

```
 add F 1 0 1
 0
 STORED
```

sequence 1
F serves and wins a point (each point gets a score of 15).

```
incr F 15
15
```

sequence 2
F serves again, and loses a point.

```
decr F 15
0
```

Please help for sequence 2. It's not updating

Answer (score 1):

```
for sequence 2 :
add N 1 0 1
0
STORED

incr N 15
30
```

Try this. It worked for me